Compiler is requiring a custom iterator to have an integral type for it to be a considered forward iterator
I'm writing an iterator for a custom collection:
template <typename T>
class List
{
public:
    class Iterator
    {

    public:

        using difference_type = T;
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = const T*;
        using reference = const T&;
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;

        Iterator(T* ptr = nullptr) : _ptr(ptr) {}
        Iterator& operator++() { _ptr++; return *this; }
        Iterator operator++(int) { Iterator retval = *this; ++(*this); return retval; }
        std::strong_ordering operator<=>(Test& other) { return _x <=> other._x; }
        bool operator==(Iterator other) const { return _ptr == other._ptr; }
        bool operator!=(Iterator other) const { return !(_ptr == other._ptr); }
        reference operator*() const { return *_ptr; }
        pointer operator->() const { return _ptr; }
        reference operator=(const T& value) { *_ptr = value; return value; }

    private:
        T* _ptr;

    };

    Iterator begin() { return Iterator(_data); }
    Iterator end() { return Iterator(_data + 4); }

    List() // Generate generic data
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            _data[i] = i + 1;
        }
    }

private:
    T _data[5];
};

This needs to be a forward iterator, but when I check this with a static assert, I can only use List<T> instances where the type T is an integral type.  Below is an example of the non-integral types float and a small Test class.  I also tested the default std::vector<Test> iterator with an identical static assert and didn't get an error.
class Test
{
public:
    Test(int x = 0) : _x(x) {}
    void Increment() { _x++; }
    std::strong_ordering operator<=>(Test& other) { return _x <=> other._x; }
    int operator=(int x) { _x = x; return x; }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Test& m) { return os << m._x; };

private:
    int _x;
};

int main()
{
    List<int> container1;
    List<Test> container2;
    List<float> container3;
    std::vector<Test> container4;

    static_assert(std::forward_iterator<decltype(container1.begin())>); // no error
    static_assert(std::forward_iterator<decltype(container2.begin())>); // ERROR
    static_assert(std::forward_iterator<decltype(container3.begin())>); // ERROR
    static_assert(std::forward_iterator<decltype(container4.begin())>); // no error

    // This loop works correctly if the static asserts are commented out
    for (List<int>::Iterator it = container1.begin(); it != container1.end(); it++)
    {
        std::cout << *it << "\n";
    }


    return 0;
}

I'm using the C++20 ISO standard with the Visual C++ compiler.  Expanding the errors gets me this error stack trace ending with the error "the constraint was not satisfied".  The error references this line in __msvc_iter_core.hpp:
template <class _Ty>
concept _Integer_like = _Is_nonbool_integral<remove_cv_t<_Ty>> || _Integer_class<_Ty>;

I don't know why an integral type would be required.  I don't think the Test class is the problem since the assert works with a vector iterator, but I don't see anything in the Iterator class that would require T to be integral.  Why is this requirement being tested?

When I get me a WTF? error diagnostic, I throw the code at a different compiler or two to see if I better understand another compiler's description of the problem. I tried to do that with your code, but it resulted in too many side issues for me to be interested in continuing. Regardless, if you can patch up what I've done, what clang and GCC have top say may still be of use to you.

using difference_type = T; should probably be something like using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;.  difference_type is the type used to represent the distance between two iterators, so It doesn't make sense for it to be a non-integral type.

Look at your operator<=>(T& other) This doesn't seem to be the code you are compiling. Also check your end() .

Part of this is also an exercise in reading error messages. From the error trace, go to line 410 of __msvc_iter_core.hpp: requires _Signed_integer_like<iter_difference_t<_Ty>>; Your difference type is not a signed integer.

The issue here is

using difference_type = T;


... which is almost certainly wrong.
Remember that the difference_type represents the difference between two iterators, and this usually doesn't depend on what they're iterating over.
Note that every iterator concept (such as std::forward_iterator<I> at the very least requires std::weakly_incrementable<I>, which has the nested requirement

typename iter_difference_t<I>;
requires is-signed-integer-like<iter_difference_t<I>>;


Having any difference_type alias at all would satisfy the first part, however, you need a signed-integer-like type as the difference the satisfy the second part.
This doesn't have to be an integral type; it can also be something very similar (e.g. MSVC's std::_Signed128 type for std::ranges::iota_view).
This is also why the standard library is testing for std::_Integer_like, not something like std::integral.
The most easy way to fix your problem would be
using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;

Unless you need extremely large differences which couldn't be represented by std::ptrdiff_t, you should use that type as a difference.

Thanks to Miles Budnek and Raymond Chen for identifying the issue in the question's comments.
The difference type of an iterator must be an integral type and since my code has the difference type as T, any non-integral T causes an error.
Writing this as an answer so I can mark the question as answered.

Just be thankful you tested with a non-integral T.   If you had only tested with integral types, the compiler would have not picked it up, but it would have been a bug all the same - albeit one harder to detect (say, if T was a smaller type than std::ptrdiff_t, in which case you would silently get undefined behaviour due to under or overflow if you had a container large enough to exceed what T can represent).
